# Invoke javascript inside iframe with AMP project

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am using Next.js with AMP enabled. 
see here: https://nextjs.org/blog/next-8-1

When i'm trying to include any javascript in my react code - the javascript is executed only on server side and stripped away for the client.

I saw [other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37106212/amp-for-complex-page) which state it is possible to execute custom javascript within `<iframe>...</iframe`

How is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

To run your custom Javascript you need to use [amp-script](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/).
You can use amp-iframe to run your custom javascript but that will run in its own workspace. You can not modify existing UI elements. Also iframe src url should be in separate domain from AMP.